# Вывод рандомного значения в блок VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Получить значение из массива по его индексу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        like: true,
        randomMovie: '',
        movies: [
            {
                'film': "Мстители, 2012",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 1
            },
            {
                'film': "Зеленая книга, 2018",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 2
            },
            {
                'film': "Аватар, 2009",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 3
            },
            {
                'film': "Волк с УолСтрит, 2013",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 4
            },
            {
                'film': "Аквамен, 2018",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 5
            },
            {
                'film': "Джон Уик, 2014",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 6
            },
            {
                'film': "Прибытие, 2016",
                'seen': true,
                'id': 7
            }
        ],
        search: ''
     },
   
    computed:{
      filteredMovies: function() {
        let filtered = this.movies;
                filtered = this.movies.filter(
                m => m.film.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search) > -1 && !m.seen);
            
        return filtered;


      },
      watched: function() {
        return this.movies.filter(function(movie) {
          return movie.seen;
        });
 
      },
    },
    methods: {
       random: function() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.movies.length);
            console.log(rand)
            this.randomMovie = this.movies[rand].film;
            
       },

       sort: function() {
        this.movies.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.film > b.film) {
              return 1;
            }
            if (a.film < b.film) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 0;
          })
       },

       liked: function() {
        this.like = !this.like
       },

       disliked: function() {

       }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="movieApp.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="app">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container__form">
                    <button v-on:click="random()">Рандом</button>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        class="input-todo" 
                        v-model="search"
                        placeholder="Поиск по фильмам"
                    >
                    <button v-on:click="sort()">Фильтр</button>
                </div>
        
                <div>
                    <ul class="container__movieList">
                        <li 
                            v-for="(movie, index) in filteredMovies" 
                            v-bind:key="movie.film"
                        >
                            <input 
                                class="container__movieList__seen" 
                                v-bind:id="'movie' + movie.id" 
                                v-model="movie.seen" 
                                type="checkbox"
                            >
                            <label v-bind:for="'movie' + movie.id">{{ movie.film }}</label>
                            <button 
                                v-bind:class="{'container__movieList__icons__liked': like === true, 
                                'container__movieList__icons__liked__isActive': like === false}" 
                                v-on:click="liked()"
                                class="container__movieList__icons
                                ">
                            </button>
                            <button 
                                v-on:click="disliked()"
                                class="container__movieList__icons
                                container__movieList__icons__disliked">
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        
                <div>
                    <p>Просмотренные</p>
                    <div v-if="watched.length <= 0">
                        <span class="container__movieList__seen1">Нет просмотренных фильмов</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="container__movieList">
                        <li 
                            v-for="(movie, index) in watched" 
                            v-bind:key="movie.film"
                            v-bind:class="{ seen: watched }"
                        >
                            <input 
                                class="container__movieList__seen" 
                                v-bind:id="'movie' + movie.id" 
                                v-model="movie.seen" 
                                type="checkbox"
                            >
                            <label v-bind:for="'movie' + movie.id">{{ movie.film }}</label>
                            <button 
                                v-bind:class="{'container__movieList__icons__liked': like === true, 
                                'container__movieList__icons__liked__isActive': like === false}" 
                                v-on:click="liked()"
                                class="container__movieList__icons
                                ">
                            </button>
                            <button 
                                v-on:click="disliked()"
                                class="container__movieList__icons
                                container__movieList__icons__disliked">
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        <div class="container2">
                <p>Посмотри сегодня:</p>
                <div v-if="!randomMovie">
                    Нажми на "Рандом" и я подберу тебе фильм на сегодняшний вечер 
                </div>
                <span v-else>{{ randomMovie }}</span>
        </div>
        </div>
    <script src="movieApp.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добрый вечер! не могли бы посмотреть этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963762/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-vue-js. Он тоже касаемо функции рандомного значения. Спасибо!